# Is there an FPT or XP algorithm known for this version of $k$-edge disjoint paths problem?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, fixed-parameter-tractable, disjoint-paths

The shortest $k$-edge disjoint paths problem is defined as follows:

> Input: An undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ and $k$ pairs of vertices $(s_1,t_1),\ldots,(s_k,t_k)$.
>
> Question: Find (if exist) $k$-pairwise edge-disjoint paths $P_1,\ldots,P_k$
> where $P_i$ goes from $s_i$ to $t_i$, such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k|P_i|$ is minimized, where $|P_i|$ denotes the number of edges in path $P_i$.

Is there a fixed-parameter tractable or an *XP* algorithm known for the problem, with parameter $k$ ?

PS: This is a related question: [For which values of $k$ is minimum length undirected $k$-disjoint-paths in $\mathcal{P}$?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21987/for-which-values-of-k-is-minimum-length-undirected-k-disjoint-paths-in-mat?rq=1).

Comment: IIRC I did some literature search for this some time ago and it seems to be open even for $k=3$.